# How to change the keyboard color to dark on Android in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-theme

My app uses dark theme as

```
ThemeData.dark().copyWith( ... ),
```

that defined for `theme` property of `MaterialApp`.

Since the `keyboardAppearance` [property](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/keyboardAppearance.html) only works on iOS, it doesn't seem to be possible to do the same on Android. Or is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in terms of **docs**, this functionality doesn't exist for android, unfortunately. This only works for ios:https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/keyboardAppearance.html

And also there is an issue opened on **GitHub** about that: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/75521

This explains that we can't make a decision in terms of the keyboard's theme from an app. The **keyboard** is a standalone application, and it's up to the keyboard to decide which theme it would take. It could have been implemented to follow the device's dark mode settings (e.g. *Samsung Galaxy's default keyboard*), or it could just provide its own settings to change themes dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the keyboard color is not possible! In Flutter, the keyboard operates as a native feature. You have the flexibility to determine whether to display it and which keyboard to show. However, since it functions as a distinct application, direct access is not possible..